# Adding and changing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome

I am trying to get a font-awesome icon to change on click.

I have a FAQ page with questions that trigger a drop down when user clicks on a question. I have accomplished this with jQuery but now I am trying to get an arrow to change to up or down after the question.

I currently have this jQuery code but it only hides the current icon without replacing it with a new icon. I see the icon sliding out to the left but I need it to just change instantly without sliding in and out.

Javascript:

```
$(this).find($(".fa")).toggle(function(){
  $(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-sort-desc');
  $(this).find($(".fa")).addClass('fa-sort');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="vraag vraag4 col-md-12" style="">
  <p class="faq1 col-md-11">Van wie krijg ik de factuur?</p>
  <div class="fa fa-sort-desc col-md-1 pijlomlaag pijlomlaag4"></div>
</div>

<div class="vragenopen vraag4open">
  <span class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML? and What does `this` refers in above code. May be you need `$(this).find(".fa").toggle('fa-sort-desc fa-sort');`

Comment: @Satpal I have enclosed the html

Comment: `$(this)` ? who is `$(this)` ?

Comment: replace `$(this)` with `$('.vraag') ` and your code must inside `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `toggle` class on `click` but not with `toggleClass()` you can use below code to toggle `fa-sort-desc` => `fa-sort` class.

```js
var s = true;
$('#arrow').click(function() {
  if (s == true) {
    s = false;
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
  } else {
    s = true;
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
  }
});
```

```css
#arrow {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a id="arrow"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

Comment: If you run your code snippet there still is the problem that the first icon is not hidden when the upwards arrow appears. Thats my biggest problem, I have achieved it already so that it jumps in and out

Comment: @JornBarkhof You used wrong icon at all, check updated answer, is it what you want?

Comment: Yea exactly. Thank you alot

Comment: @JornBarkhof Glad to help.